# how to set a progress bar in saving data to mysql database in java?

Tags: java, mysql

Peace be with you all, Any one know or has a source code of saving a data with progress bar.
* the user can view the status saving even if the data is text.
* the user also can cancel the saving of data for instance there are many data.
* the user can click the background process to be able to run on background or then user can do other process. (Multi Threading)..

I've been searching on google for a week. yes there is a sample progress bar but i really don't understand . any one can help me out? please...  thank you .. peace be with you..

[image: Saving with progress or loading]

Comment: Hello sir @Nicolas Filotto, can you help me sir, thank you in advance

Comment: So, create two threads. In the db work thread define a "total query count" and and "progress". Poll that every x ms from the ui thread to display it on the gui/your progressbar.

Comment: thanks I've got what you mean, but I really cant code. it haha no idea lmao. :D need more practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         Runnable dbThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dodbwork(); //as mentioned by Nicolas do your Database work here
    }
};
         Runnable uiThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doUIUpdates(); // and your UI work here
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);//telling your thread to wait in  milliseconds
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(saveprogressbar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
};
         dbThread.run();//this is how you run your thread later on
         uiThread.run();
```

Comment: Well. I guess you need a infinite loop (until the db work is done) in the ui thread. Otherwise this is a short game ^^

Comment: Ofc. but im not here to do his project just to give him a hint. he has to do his own logic

Comment: thank you GoneUp, Ive try this but the execution is not on the same time the dbThread will run if I close the dialogloading, i want it while running the UI also dbthread running. something wrong with my code idk where huhuh.

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it ;)